# handle url pagination with python generator

Tags: python

Currently I'm fetching only first page from the server, part of the `json` is

```
{"status":"success","count":100,"total":22188,"next":"https://pimber.ly/api/v2/products/?sinceId=5981e16fcde47c0854dc540b","previous":"https://pimber.ly/api/v2/products/?maxId=5981e01dcde47c0854dc4afd","sinceId":"5981e01dcde47c0854dc4afd","maxId":"5981e16fcde47c0854dc540b","data":[.....]}
```

and the function is:

```
_fetch_data = response.json()
while _fetch_data['next'] is not None:
    response = requests.get(
        url=API_DOMAIN',
        headers=headers
    )
    _page_data = response.json()['data']
    for _data in _page_data:
        yield _data
```

Current state of the function is only processing the first page, and it will just do that forever, so how can i fix the function to check `next` so can fetch `total` data?

Comment: `url=API_DOMAIN'` isn't there an extra `'`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @Pynchia yup it's an extra, Bartosz example is a good hint, but still not getting to the next page only hitting the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be

```
_fetch_data = response.json()
while _fetch_data['next'] is not None:
    response = requests.get(_fetch_data['next'], headers=headers)
    _fetch_data = response.json()
    for _data in fetch_data['data']:
        yield _data
```

Comment: ok, this is correct answer, the docs from the provider are strange, so it's working now